# Account merged into previous account used by another user

Tags: support, user-accounts

This system is previously used by a lady "Mary", now I'm using this computer. It's my office computer.

Today I created a new Stack Overflow account, but now my account details were merged with her details.

How can I create a new account from this computer? I don't want to use her reputation in my name. Please help me.

Comment: I would expect that cookies and caches are saved per-user on a machine that has more than one user. You are reusing her profile as well?

Comment: Notes: user's account created: 10 June 2011. First activity (question asked/rep earned): 4 Oct. Merged accounts: none.

Comment: I've created my account 14 days before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email team@stackoverflow.com with the account details.

I can see your SO account is Midhun https://stackoverflow.com/users/792459/midhun

Let them know which account "Mary"'s was and they should be able to unmerge these accounts.

Next, Clear all browser cookies and caches and start again

Comment: I am not aware of any operating system that requires different users to share the same account.  I hate to offend, but it's true: automatic login is not smart.